# Erosion and Dilation of Image in one direction using Scipy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy.ndimage

I have an elevation array from a .tif LiDAR surface. Example array below.

```
Existing_example_arrayV0 = [[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                            [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                            [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                            [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                            [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                            [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The below code erodes the image equally from all sides.

```
    for i in range(0, 1):  
    erosion_mask = binary_erosion(Existing_example_arrayV0 >= 100, structure=np.ones((3, 3)), iterations=i)
    Existing_example_arrayV0[erosion_mask] += 100

    Proposed_example_array = [[ 0,  0,   1,   0,   0,  0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101,  1,   0,  0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101, 101,  1,  0, 0], 
                              [ 1, 100, 101, 101,  1,  0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101, 101,  1,  0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,   1,   0,   0,  0, 0]]
```

Is there a way to change the structure to only erode the image from one side to produce the below `proposed_example_array`?

Eroded from left only:

```
    Proposed_example_array = [[ 0,  0,   1,   0,   0,  0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101, 101,  0,  0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101, 101, 101, 0, 0], 
                              [ 1, 100, 101, 101, 101, 0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101, 101, 101, 0, 0], 
                              [ 0,  1,  101,  0,   0,  0, 0]]
```

Eroded from right only:

```
    Proposed_example_array = [[  0,   0,    1,   0,  0,  0, 0], 
                              [  0,  101,  101,  1,  0,  0, 0], 
                              [  0,  101,  101, 101, 1,  0, 0], 
                              [ 101, 101,  101, 101, 1,  0, 0], 
                              [  0,  101,  101, 101, 1,  0, 0], 
                              [  0,  101,   1,   0,  0,  0, 0]]
```

Comment: In your first proposed example array, should the element at y=4 x=3 not be 1? It's on the edge.

Comment: Yes! I believe you are correct. Do you have any recommendations to achieve the desired output array?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to have at least one non-zero element in each row?

Comment: Yes! the input array will always have at least one non-zero element in each row. I have been doing a fair bit of research and I'm not positive if I can achieve the desired output by changing the structure? But it seems to be my more promising lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy is not necessary here; drop down to Numpy. `argmax()` has the behaviour that it returns the index of the first maximum value, in your case 1, over the specified axis. This can be applied in reverse by `::-1` on the second axis for the right-hand case.

```py
import numpy as np

existing_example_arrayV0 = np.array([
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])

left_erode = 101*existing_example_arrayV0
right_erode = left_erode.copy()
y = np.arange(existing_example_arrayV0.shape[0])
left_erode[y, existing_example_arrayV0.argmax(axis=1)] = 1
right_erode[y, -1-existing_example_arrayV0[:, ::-1].argmax(axis=1)] = 1
```

```
[[  0   0   1   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   1 101 101   0   0   0]
 [  0   1 101 101 101   0   0]
 [  1 101 101 101 101   0   0]
 [  0   1 101 101 101   0   0]
 [  0   1 101   0   0   0   0]]
[[  0   0   1   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 101 101   1   0   0   0]
 [  0 101 101 101   1   0   0]
 [101 101 101 101   1   0   0]
 [  0 101 101 101   1   0   0]
 [  0 101   1   0   0   0   0]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Would there be a similar methodology instead of left/right, a program that would run top/bottom or bottom/top?

Comment: Yes - transpose (`.T`) the array and then run the same code

Comment: is it possible to then add a second iteration where for example in the left iterating code the second maximum number in every row is held constant while values to the right are filled again?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean. If you're unable to come up with a solution for that then you should post a new question.

Comment: Let me clarify. Can .argmax return the next value after the maximum.